# PCV valve won’t fit my 08 Dodge Avenger SXT

Tags: engine

I have an 08 Dodge Avenger SXT 2.7L that the PCV valve was broken. Ask me how, I have no idea. So, I took it to my mechanic, he can’t find the part. He is requesting to replace a section just because of that part. Everywhere else, such as auto parts and oreiley auto parts sells one that won’t fit. See the photos[image: this is the insert part. The thread][image]

Comment: Well, some parts are only available as complete sub-assemblies...

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the actual question you are asking?

Comment: Mechanic can't find the part, go figure.  Your next step is to get the part direct from a dodge dealership or go to a salvage yard

Comment: Im having the exact problem. Removed mine and replacement is to small at the threads. Dealer wants to replace valve cover. LOL. did you find a fix for this?